# Why interface table is not generated for the child class?

Tags: delphi, interface, polymorphism

I have following problem:

- One base class which implements a certain interface
- Another class which descends from the base class and overrides the interface method

For the child class the interface table is not generated at all.

```
type
  ITest = interface
    ['{69068A88-6712-40E0-B1E3-DA265F7428EA}']
    procedure Test;
  end;

  TBase = class(TInterfacedObject, ITest)
  protected
    procedure Test; virtual;
  public
    constructor Create;
  end;

  TChild = class(TBase)
  protected
    procedure Test; override;
  end;

constructor TBase.Create;
begin
  Assert(GetInterfaceTable <> nil);
end;
```

so when using following construction:

```
var
  X: ITest;
begin
  X := TChild.Create;
end;
```

I get the assertion failed.

So **I do know that I need to re-declare the interfaces in the class declaration** to fix this problem. But is that a language feature or an compiler old-old issue?

Because at compile time the compiler knows that the TChild is implementing the ITest interface. But once we go to run-time I do need to make duplicate re-declaration of the interfaces from the base! Why should we do that? For me it looks buggy.

Comment: David Heffernan will tell you that declaring an interface method as virtual and overriding it in a derived class is irrelevant to interfaces. You can do it but it is useless. If you need to change an interface method in a derived class you should redeclare the interface in the derived class, and the method changed can be static - no need to make it virtual.

Comment: That makes sense in a way of speed but not in my case. All classes share the same interface and SOME of the classes can override the methods. But anyway problem is solved - it was in IoC container and parsing the parent classes made the thing.

Answer (score 2):

As documented [GetInterfaceTable](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.TObject.GetInterfaceTable) returns list of interface entries for the class. In your case that is `TChild` that does not have any interfaces implemented by itself.

> Returns a pointer to a structure containing all of the interfaces
>   implemented by a given class.
>
> GetInterfaceTable returns the interface entries for the class. This
>   list contains only interfaces implemented by this class, not its
>   ancestors. To find the ancestor list, iteratively call ClassParent and
>   then call GetInterfaceTable on the value it returns. To find the entry
>   for a specific interface, use the GetInterfaceEntry method instead.

`GetInterfaceTable` is class function, just like `ClassName` is class function. It depends on instance class not on from which part of code you have called it:

If you run following code it will give you different `ClassName` regardless of the fact you are calling code in `TBase` constructor.

```
constructor TBase.Create;
begin
  writeln(ClassName);
end;

var
  x : ITest;

   X := TBase.Create; // outputs TBase
   X := TChild.Create; // outputs TChild
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's what I thought and now I will be sure about that :)

Answer (score 1):

It is as designed.

AFAIR `GetInterfaceTable` is a very low-level method, which works only at a given class level. You should not have to use this method in your code, unless you are messing with the low-level RTTI information... but in all cases, you should better not use it.

Here how it is implemented:

```
class function TObject.GetInterfaceTable: PInterfaceTable;
begin
  Result := PPointer(PByte(Self) + vmtIntfTable)^;
end;
```

So you would have to check the parent classes types, too, using a recursive call or a loop.

For instance, here is a sample of its use in System.pas:

```
class function TObject.InitInstance(Instance: Pointer): TObject;
var
  IntfTable: PInterfaceTable;
  ClassPtr: TClass;
  I: Integer;
begin
  FillChar(Instance^, InstanceSize, 0);
  PPointer(Instance)^ := Pointer(Self);
  ClassPtr := Self;
  while ClassPtr <> nil do
  begin
    IntfTable := ClassPtr.GetInterfaceTable;
    if IntfTable <> nil then
      for I := 0 to IntfTable.EntryCount-1 do
        with IntfTable.Entries[I] do
        begin
          if VTable <> nil then
            PPointer(@PByte(Instance)[IOffset])^ := VTable;
        end;
    ClassPtr := ClassPtr.ClassParent;
  end;
  Result := Instance;
end;
```

Pretty low-level stuff, isn't it?

To implement an IoC pattern, you would rather have to use `TObject.GetInterfaceEntry()`, which does what you expect.

Comment: This is used for the IoC container.

Comment: And it works when calling Supports().. probably I just need then to go through the ClassParent.GetInterfaceTable...

Comment: See  how we implemented TServiceContainerServer.AddImplementation in mORMot.pas - https://github.com/synopse/mORMot/blob/master/SQLite3/mORMot.pas

Comment: @ZENsan Supports() uses the GUID to search for the whole Entries[] of all inheritance hierarchy, using a ClassPtr.ClassParent loop - it calls in fact TObject.GetInterfaceEntry() which is perhaps the function you need to use.

Comment: Thats what I just did - a loop through the parent classes. As i need to register all the interfaces implemented by the class in a certain case.

Comment: About low-level - agree. But I do not need all that low level stuff. I just need to go through the InterfaceTable through the class hierarchy.